# Error using await / async with Puppeter functions

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to place a series of consecutive steps that I will repeat several times within my program, such as logging in, searching for some data criteria in a form or ending the session.

This is the way I put the steps of Puppeter within functions

```
login: function (page, selector){
    (async () => {
        await page.goto(“localhost:8080/login”);
        await page.type(“#username”, “admin”);
        console.log("STEP 1 USERNAME”);
        await page.type(“#password”, “admin1”);
        console.log("STEP 2 PASSWORD”);
        await page.waitForSelector(“#submit”).then(() =>
            page.click(“#submit”)
        );
        console.log("STEP 3 - Login"); 
    })();
}
```

This is my main js program (`main.js`)

```
CASE1: function (req, res) {
        (async () => {
            const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            try {
                console.log("STARTING CASE 1”);
                await page.setViewport({ "width": 1280, "height": 720 });
                login (page, selector);
                await page.waitForSelector(“#combobox_of_day”).then(() =>
                    page.click(“#combobox_of_day”)
                );
                console.log("SELECT combobox of day”);

await page.waitForSelector(“#combobox_of_month”).then(() =>
                    page.click(“#combobox_of_month”)
                );
                console.log("SELECT combobox of month”);
await page.waitForSelector(“#combobox_of_year”).then(() =>
                    page.click(“#combobox_of_ year”)
                );
                console.log("SELECT combobox of year”);
                await browser.close(); 
             console.log("ENDING navigation”);

            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);

            }
        })();
    }
```

So at the NodeJS console I would expect to see something like that

```
STARTING CASE 1
STEP 1 USERNAME
STEP 2 PASSWORD
STEP 3 Login
SELECT combobox of day
SELECT combobox of month
SELECT combobox of year
ENDING navigation
```

**But what you get on the console is something like this**

```
STARTING CASE 1
STEP 1 USERNAME
SELECT combobox of day
SELECT combobox of month
SELECT combobox of year
STEP 2 PASSWORD
STEP 3 Login
ENDING navigation
```

And finely an error message

```
{ TimeoutError: waiting for selector "#username" failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded
    at new WaitTask (Z:\Documents\AR-puppeter\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\FrameManager.js:864:28)
    at Frame._waitForSelectorOrXPath (Z:\Documents\AR-puppeter\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\FrameManager.js:755:12)
    at Frame.waitForSelector (Z:\Documents\AR-puppeter\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\FrameManager.js:713:17)
    at Page.waitForSelector (Z:\Documents\AR-puppeter\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:1017:29)
    at Z:\Documents\AR-puppeter\pruebas-app-ar\modulos\escenarios\escenario.js:145:28
    at <anonymous> name: 'TimeoutError' }
```

Since it seems that the problem is that calling the function "`Login ()`" is not stopping the execution of consecutive lines.

How can I make the program (`main.js`) wait for all the steps of my "`Login ()`" function to continue?

This is not solved with the use of `async / await` and `WaitForSelector`?

I tried using different syntaxes when calling the "`Login ()`" function from my program (`main.js`) but I got the same error.

```
async login (page, selector); //Getting same error

await login (page, selector); //Getting same error
```

Comment: Try using try.. catch in login function and check for any error and debug it..

Then use await login in CASE1 function..

I think if you use await in the current scenario, you are getting the timeout error.

Comment: In login function, you need to wait for the page load using networkidle in page.goto as an option. here is the documentation https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.7.0/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.

Right now I am considering it for the implementation of my program with Puppeter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formulation of `login` is strange: you use an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to run an `async` function, but since the wrapper is not `async`, you never wait for the promise. You don’t wait for `login` in `CASE1` either, but then you can’t do that, since it doesn’t return anything. You need to first make `login` return a `Promise` by making it `async` (you could return a `Promise` without making it `async`, but then you wouldn’t be able to use `await` inside it):

```
login: async (page, selector) => {
  await page.goto("localhost:8080/login");
  await page.type("#username", "admin");
  console.log("STEP 1 USERNAME");
  await page.type("#password", "admin1");
  console.log("STEP 2 PASSWORD");
  const submit = await page.waitForSelector("#submit");
  await submit.click();
  console.log("STEP 3 - Login");
}
```

[`waitForSelector` returns the `ElementHandle`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#framewaitforselectorselector-options), so you don’t need to call `page.click` separately, and you don’t need to use `then` in any case. Now `login` returns a `Promise`.

Next, you need to `await` that `Promise` in `CASE1` and remove the IIFE in favour of making the function itself `async`:

```
CASE1: async (req, res) => {
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    try {
      console.log("STARTING CASE 1");
      await page.setViewport({ "width": 1280, "height": 720 });
      await login(page, selector);

      for (const type of ["day", "month", "year"]) {
        const combobox = await page.waitForSelector(`#combobox_of_${type}`);
        await combobox.click();
        console.log(`SELECT combobox of ${type}`);
      }

      await browser.close(); 
      console.log("ENDING navigation");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
}
```

I removed some of the repetition. There doesn’t seem to be a `selector` variable, which is just as well as since `login` ignores it, but I left it in anyway to match your code.

By the way, avoid using word processors to handle code. I had to first spend some time fixing the smart quotes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.

Right now I am considering it for the implementation of my program with Puppeter.